# How do I write a nested query to display the customer names and credit limit with a lower credit limit than the customer in cit in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

The following is my CUSTOMERS table:

```
create table CUSTOMERS
    (CustID      char(6)       unique Not null,
     Name        varchar(45),
     Address     varchar(40),
     City        varchar(30),
     State       varchar(2),
     Zip         varchar(9),
     AreaCode    char(3),
     Phone       varchar (9),
     RepID       char(4)       not null,
     CreditLimit decimal(9,2),
     Primary key(CustID),
         Foreign key(RepID) References EMPLOYEES(EmpID));




insert into CUSTOMERS values (100,'Jocksports','345 Viewridge','Belmont','CA','96711',415,'598-6609',7844,5000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (101,'TKB Sport Shop','490 Boli Rd.','Redwood City','CA','94061',415,'368-1223',7521,10000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (102,'Vollyrite','9722 Hamilton','Burlingame','CA','95133',415,'644-3341',7654,7000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (103,'Just Tennis','Hillview Mall','Burlingame','CA','97544',415,'677-9312',7521,3000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (104,'Every Mountain','574 Surry Rd.','Cupertino','CA','93301',408,'996-2323',7499,10000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (105,'K + T Sports','3476 El Paseo','Santa Clara','CA','91003',408,'376-9966',7844,5000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (106,'Shape Up','908 Sequoia','Palo Alto','CA','94301',415,'364-9777',7521,6000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (107,'Womens Sports','Valco Village','Sunnyvale','CA','93301',408,'967-4398',7499,10000);
insert into CUSTOMERS values (108,'North Woods Fitness Supply Center','98 Lone Pine Way','Hibbing','MN','55649',612,'566-9123',7844,8000);
```

The following is my query I need amended:

```
select name, creditlimit
from CUSTOMERS
where name in
(select name
from CUSTOMERS
where City = 'sunnyvale');
```

I can't find examples anywhere to answer the following prompt:

Write the nested query to display the customer names and credit limit with a lower credit limit than the customer in Sunnyvale. List lowest credit limit first.

Comment: what if there are multiple customers from `Sunnyvale`, do you need to get the lowest credit limit from `Sunnyvale` and compare it with other customer?

Comment: AAAAH....Im supposed to do this query without knowing that there is only 1 customer in sunnyvale.  So I would get the MIN of Sunnyvale.  but I still am confused about the syntax.  I cant find an example in my book nor a good one on the WEB

Comment: Actually, by the prompt it states "than "the" customer in Sunnyvale" maybe saying that I already know that there is only one customer in sunnyvale.  But I dont know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Name,CREDITLIMIT FROM  CUSTOMERS 
WHERE CREDITLIMIT < (SELECT CREDITLIMIT FROM CUSTOMERS 
                     WHERE CITY = 'Sunnyvale')
ORDER BY CREDITLIMIT
```

if multiple customers in Sunnyvale you can use MIN or MAX

```
SELECT Name,CREDITLIMIT FROM  CUSTOMERS 
WHERE CREDITLIMIT < (SELECT MAX(CREDITLIMIT) FROM CUSTOMERS 
                     WHERE CITY = 'Sunnyvale')
ORDER BY CREDITLIMIT
```

Comment: I could also DISTINCT, right?...never mind, you weren't talking about dupes.

Answer (score 2):

This query will result in Order what you want.

```
   SELECT CreditLimit, Name
    FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE CreditLimit < ( 
    SELECT CreditLImit
    FROM CUSTOMERS
    WHERE City =  'sunnyvale' ) 
    ORDER BY CreditLimit
```

Comment: anytime :)
if you want to change the order, just add 
`ORDER BY desc`
 to your query and it would show the result in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, creditlimit
from CUSTOMERS
where creditlimit <
(select CreditLimit
from CUSTOMERS
where City = 'sunnyvale') order by CreditLimit
```

Try Above Query.

**Here is the Demo:**

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81187/2)